# Querying Pods.io for related records

Tags: wordpress, podscms

This is going to drive me absolutely crazy. I have custom content types using Pods and I am trying to get all related records based on a parent. In this case I have states and counties.

I start with:

```
$states = pods( 'state', $params);
```

And sure enough I get all the states entered. Next I want to loop through all the states and get the counties that are related to the state by the 'state_id' but have no idea on how to do that. Here is what I have.

```
while ( $states->fetch() ) {
    echo $states->display( 'state_name' ) . "<br />";
    $params = [
        'where'=>"meta_value.state_id = 19"
    ];
    $county = pods( 'county', $params);
    print_r($county);
}
```

Of course the where clause is wrong but the documentation is confusing at best. I see things like 'related_field_name.meta_value' or 'related_field_name.field_name'. I tried the above query with the where clause having `state.meta_value=19` (the state ID that is related to the county) and it just given me a huge list of information but no records.

In the wordpress database I have the wp_postmeta which contains a number of meta_key and meta_value for the county record including one meta_key of 'state_id' with the value of '19' which I want to match up in the loop.

How can I say 'Grab me all the post records that have an state_id of 19'?

Comment: A couple quick questions before I can give you the final answer:

1. What pod type is State and County?
2. Is that a relationship field that relates to States on the County pod?

Comment: The pods are state and county. The county has a meta value of the post ID of the state called 'state_id' (for the meta_key)

Comment: So they are both "post type" pods, using "meta-based storage"?

Comment: If they are post type pods, why do you have a "state_name" field? Maybe I'm confused here, or perhaps you've added redundant fields, but "state_name" isn't needed because posts get "post_title".

Comment: Ok, both seem to work. I believe I am using meta-storage since all the information is being stored in the meta_key and meta_value columns.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<?php
$params = array(
    'limit' => -1,
);

$states = pods( 'state', $params );

while ( $states->fetch() ) {
    // Pods::index() maps to "post_title"
    echo '<h3>' . $states->index() . '</h3>';

    // Pods::id() maps to "ID"
    $county_params = array(
        'where' => 'state_id.meta_value = ' . (int) $states->id(),
    );

    /*
    // If you had a relationship field instead
    // and the field was named "state"
    // and it was related to the "state" post type
    // then it would be:
    $county_params = array(
        'where' => 'state.ID = ' . (int) $states->id(),
    );
    */

    $county = pods( 'county', $county_params );

    // List all counties for state
    if ( 0 < $county->total() ) {
        echo '<ul>';

        while ( $county->fetch() ) {
            // index() maps to "post_title"
            echo '<li>' . $county->index() . '</li>';
        }

        echo '</ul>';
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm getting Response: Unknown column 'state_id.meta_value' in 'where clause' for the first example and Response: Unknown column 'state.ID' in 'where clause' in the other one. The state_is the meta_key for the county.

Comment: What about state_id.ID?